# Looking for Chatbot recommendations with API GET function

Tags: api, get, chatbot

I'm in EU and I am looking for a new chatbot which has API GET functionality.
Also the basic Greeting and few navigation buttons

Example:
Client comes to a site
Chatbot window pops out says greetings etc..
Has multiple choice what to do, but press tab/button "Search my parcel" and then enters parcel ID, then the GET URL will give client latest delivery status.

I have searched lot of these already, but not have found the perfect easy solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think Botonic (https://github.com/hubtype/botonic) would be a good choice for you. As it's open-source and Javascript/React based, you can do anything you want really, with the advantage of being fully customisable.

Check out the examples section on the website to see if it fits your needs: https://botonic.io/examples/

[I'm one of the creators of this framework]